# moment.duration string giving nan value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have a problem about **moment.duration** giving me a **NAN** value. In the documentation it says that it's okay to give it a string value `moment.duration(String)`. I'm fairly lost here and getting nowhere.

**vm.generatedData value**

```
vm.generatedData = [{ overtime: 'Mon Nov 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)' }, { overtime: 'Wed Nov 29 2017 02:25:00 GMT+0800 (+08)' }];
```

**controller**

```
function getTotalOvertime() {
  var total = 0;
  console.log(vm.generatedData);

  for (var x = 0; x < vm.generatedData.length; x++) {

    var format = moment(vm.generatedData[x].overtime).format('HH:mm:ss');
    vm.add += moment.duration(format);
    console.log(vm.add); // NAN VALUE
    var d = moment.duration(vm.add);
    vm.totalOT = parseInt(d.asHours()) + ':' + d.minutes();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't with moment, it is that `vm.add` doesn't have a value yet. Set `vm.add = 0` along with `total`, and you should see it work again.

You can check this out by logging `moment.duration(format)`, and see that it returns a number.